# Windows Server 2008 R2 Server Core with AD Role having GUI Admin Console

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-core

I would like to setup a machine with **Windows Server 2008 R2 Server Core** and install following server roles:

- Active Directory Domain Services
- Active Directory Federation Services
- Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (I'm not sure whether I actually need this one - see note below)

I'm obviously going to install Enterprise Edition.

### Question

Can I have an AD administration graphical user interface to manage Active Directory on Server Core machine? I would really like to have it, because I'm not so keen to do stuff using power-shell, because I've never managed AD as well, so a GUI would be much more helpful, because I could at least visualize it a bit better and *maybe* understand AD structures.

> **Note**: I'm setting up development environment machine as well and installing Sharepoint Foundation 2010 on in so it would use this AD machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best bet is to run the the [Remote Server Administration tools (RSAT)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9ff6e897-23ce-4a36-b7fc-d52065de9960&displaylang=en) on a desktop/server in the domain which will allow you to [connect to the server core machine remotely](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449467%28WS.10%29.aspx) & use the GUI tools.

In addition, you might also want to run & install [Core Configurator](http://coreconfig.codeplex.com/) on the core box, which will let you do some basic AD & server admin without having to look up all the commands :)

Comment: This is great information, except that **Remote Server Admin tools** I will use are for Windows 7 and can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449475%28WS.10%29.aspx